# Error while using Date Commands in bcp sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, bcp

Hi I've been trying to Copy Data from a query to a file using bcp command.It works fine when I dont list any DATE Commands in where condition.But since I want a file each for every date.I tried inserting date but it is giving an error

Can you please suggest me the correct method to make this work.

I tried it using the below commands.

```
declare @sql varchar(8000)
DECLARE @dated date =  GETDATE()    

set @sql= 'select top 10 [Message],Received_Time from TURBO..Receive_Message_Mst where dcs_value<>8 and DATEDIFF(dd,Received_Time,'@dated') = 1'
Print @sql
set @sql = 'bcp "'+@sql+'" queryout C:\DPFiles\Test1.csv -c -t,-T -S '
Print @sql
exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql
```

and I got the error

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near '@dated'.

I tried a different one and got the below error:

```
declare @sql varchar(8000)
DECLARE @dated date =  GETDATE()    

set @sql= 'select top 10 [Message],Received_Time from TURBO..Receive_Message_Mst where dcs_value<>8 and DATEDIFF(dd,Received_Time,'+@dated+') = 1'
Print @sql
set @sql = 'bcp "'+@sql+'" queryout C:\DPFiles\Test1.csv -c -t,-T -S '
Print @sql
exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql
```

Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
The data types varchar and date are incompatible in the add operator.

However it works fine when i remove and DATEDIFF(dd,Received_Time,'+@dated+') = 1 from the above query.

Comment: Why do you need a variable if you are going to assign `getdate()` to it?

Comment: Hi shreepat...I tried even that using getdate() directly instead of a variable but I get the below error though I've specified as a trusted connection.                                                             User name not provided, either use -U to provide the user name or use -T for Trusted Connection

Comment: Yeah that's because of the way you construct your query, as the error clearly states. You might want to try my proposed solution.

Comment: sorry but Even your Solution gives the same error asking to use -U to provide username or -T for trusted connection..

Comment: Did you use the exact same thing that I posted? If you are still using + to concatenate, then it will fail.

Comment: I just did exactly as you suggested but still the same problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59792/discussion-between-shree-pat18-and-vjai).

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to just assign `GETDATE()`, I would argue against using a variable at all. However, to make this code work with the variable, you can change your code to this:

```
declare @sql varchar(8000)

set @sql= 'DECLARE @dated date =  GETDATE(); ' 
set @sql = @sql + 'select top 10 [Message],Received_Time from TURBO..Receive_Message_Mst where dcs_value<>8 and DATEDIFF(dd,Received_Time,@dated) = 1'
```

What we are doing is simply declaring the variable within the dynamic query string and then passing in like we normally pass a variable to a query.

There is another thing to change here:

```
set @sql = 'bcp "'+@sql+'" queryout C:\DPFiles\Test1.csv -c -t "," -T -S '
```

`-t` specifies the field terminator, so you need to enclose that character in double quotes and have a space before and after it i.e. `-t "," T`.